# /hbase/meta-region-server because node does not exist (not an error)

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I'm running hbase in a cluster mode and I'm getting the following error:

DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil  - catalogtracker-on-hconnection-0x6e704bd0x0, quorum=node2:2181, baseZNode=/hbase Set watcher on znode that does not yet exist, /hbase/meta-region-server

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar the error and got it resolved by doing these:

1) Making sure HBase Client Version is compatible with the HBase version on the cluster.
2) Adding hbase-site.xml to your application classpath, so that HBase client determines all the appropriate HBase configurations from it.

```
val conf = org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration.create()
// Instead of the following settings, pass hbase-site.xml in classpath 
// conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", hbaseHost)
// conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", hbasePort)

HBaseAdmin.checkHBaseAvailable(conf);
log.debug("HBase found! with conf " + conf);
```